# Search and replace moduleFor('foo:bar') with moduleFor('foo:bar', 'unit@foo:bar')

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, qunit

I am working with a large set of qunit unit tests in a folder called "tests". At the top of each file is the following, for example:

```
moduleFor('mixin:foo')

// or

moduleFor('route:bar')
```

I'd like to write a search and replace for these files such that each occurrence would be replaced with this updated style:

```
moduleFor('mixin:foo', 'unit@mixin:foo')

// or 

moduleFor('route:bar', 'unit@route:foo')
```

Comment: Check [this solution](https://www.regex101.com/r/YgSMgW/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first line of your file is this line, you can use this, with multiline flag on.

`\AmoduleFor\('(.*?)'\)$`

Where `\A` always matches the beginning of the input data (file in this case). `$` because of the multiline flag, matches the end of the line (not the input). You can also probably remove the `$` in case of following whitespace or comments you don't want to affect. If this is always the total first line, I'd leave the `$`.

In this example [here](https://regex101.com/r/U6evRd/1), I deliberately use `^` to match the beginning of the *line* rather than the *input*, merely for demonstration purposes.

---

I'm not familiar with qunit and if there might be no other occurences of module in the file, if there is not, assertions shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Worked a charm. In atom I did a search in folder using and replaced using regex. Search for: `moduleFor\('(.*?)'` and replace with `moduleFor('$1', 'unit@$1')`